# Singular values uniquely determined for a matrix, does that mean $A=B$ IFF $\Sigma_A=\Sigma_B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal, svd, orthogonal-matrices, singular-values

I have heard it often that singular values for the SVD are "uniquely determined by the matrix $A$ in $A=U\Sigma V^*$

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition) says it, and so do other sources.

Now, I want to check how I am applying the aforementioned fact.  I'm solving this problem:

> If A and B have the same singular values, are they unitarily equivalent?

My answer to this is "yes", because singular values are unique for each matrix.  So not only are they unitarily equivalent, but they are the *same matrix*.

However, I see other answers to this question as this is false?  (For example [here](https://github.com/markhkim/trefethen-bau/blob/master/04-the_singular_value_decomposition.ipynb) in *Exercise 4.4*).

What is generally meant by "uniqueness of singular values if it does not meant that each set of singular values corresponds to a different matrix?

Comment: $U_1\Sigma V_1^*\neq U_2\Sigma V_2^*$

Comment: Uniqueness of singular values for a given matrix A means that given A, the singular values themselves are uniquely determined (if you and I both are given the task to perform a SVD on a given matrix, our singular values will necessarily be the same). This statement says nothing about two matrices that have the same singular values

Comment: However, if $A = U_1\Sigma V_1^*$ and $B = U_2\Sigma V_2^*$, then $A = (U_1U_2^*)B(V_2V_1^*)$. Hence, they are unitarily equivalent.

Comment: Thank you.  So, I'm trying to get the terminology correct here:  if two matrices always had different singular values, would that be called "distinct and unique"?  "unique" seems to have a different meaning from what I thought.  Thank you @D.Beec